# Experience Editor changes force refresh

Tags: experience-editor

When in Experience Editor making changes to some fields, such as a multilist that could control a rendering of items to show, do not reflect on the page until it is saved. This can be confusing and cumbersome for content editors.

Is there a way to force a save and refresh when editing these items in Experience Editor to make the content editing experience better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote a blog post on this a while ago: http://www.flux-digital.com/blog/refreshing-experience-page-editor-after-using-edit-frames-or-buttons/

One word of caution though, we did see some odd issues caused by this firing and causing a save on components where it wasn't needed. So I'd suggest perhaps checking your templates(s) before firing the save, something like the following (not tested):

```
if (item != null)
{
 if(item.TemplateID == MyTemplateIds.MyBannerTemplate.ID){
  item.Editing.BeginEdit();
  item.Fields[fieldInfo.FieldID.ToString()].Value = str1;
  item.Editing.EndEdit();
 }
}
```

I'll update the blog post at some point to include info on this but Let me know if you find a better way of doing this or if this works for you.

Comment: I like this approach. I'm wondering if there is a way to also inform the page that the save has happened so the user doesn't need to see that prompt on refresh.

Comment: I might be possible using the JavaScript api but I've never done it so I'm not sure to be honest.