# Adding Item With Experience Editor Button Attempts to Trigger a Page Refresh

Tags: experience-editor

I have a rendering which has an edit frame for a list of items that are children of the datasource item of the rendering. The issue I'm dealing with happens when I follow these steps:

1. Add the rendering to the page
2. Create a datasource item in the popup after adding a rendering
3. Add an item under the datasource item using the insert option on the rendering

At this point I will receive [this alert](https://www.screencast.com/t/KGmbrfBTLUW). I realize [this question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/514/1436) is close to my issue. Is there a way to make it so the page does not refresh when an item is added with the insert button? I would expect it to work in a similar way to the prompt to select associate content for a rendering if this is possible.

Comment: Teeknow. I'd suggest that instead of having nested child items like this you refactor to use multilist field within your data source to select your child Items. You can then use the field selector popup within experience editor to select the child items which shouldn't cause a page refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deal with this issue I ended up refactoring the children items to have their own renderings (`Accordion Section`) and be inserted into my datasource folder rather than nested under my accordion item. My `Accordion` rendering changed to pretty much just have markup to show a title field and a placeholder which allows `Accordion Section` renderings. I could have removed the datasource item for this rendering if there wasn't a title field to be displayed along with each accordion and it was just going to be the placeholder that allows adding `Accordion Section` renderings.

This fixes my issue involving the refresh alert however it will be a little less obvious how this module works in content editor because there isn't a hierarchy shown in the tree, it's all based on where the rendering is. For example my tree can look like this:

```
Page
  _datasourceFolder
    Accordion
    Accordion Section 1
    Accordion Section 2
```

The order that `Accordion Section 1` and `Accordion Section 2` show up in the tree does not really matter. The order is determined by the renderings that point to them on the item noted as `Page`. I wanted to nest these under the item noted as `Accordion`. I almost got this working with a query for the datasource location for my `Accordion Section` rendering however in the event that there are 2 accordions on a page this fell apart so I left the datasource locations of those to be my datasource folder. Since my client is going to be far more reliant on experience editor mode rather than content editor mode this should be fine.